# SQL: Is there any way to read BLOBs from a database into an array instead of FileOutputStream in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, blob

I am trying to do the following: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/read-file-data-from-database-using-jdbc

except instead of using

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
```

and

```
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

I am hoping that I can create an arraylist of images and simply store all of the images in there? The reason is that the images I am getting from the database all belong to one particular user and I don't want them saved in a file on the hard disk.

Comment: read the stream and store it, internally, however you want.

Comment: If the Blob is an image, and you're just going to keep the entire image in memory anyway, don't use the JDBC [`getBlob()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBlob-java.lang.String-) or [`getBinaryStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream-java.lang.String-) methods. Just call [`getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBytes-java.lang.String-) to get the `byte[]`. You can then easily store multiple images in a `List<byte[]>` or `List<BufferedImage>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the images as **BufferedImage**(s):

```
ArrayList< BufferedImage > listOfImages = new ArrayList< BufferedImage >();

if (result.next()) {
    Blob blob = result.getBlob("photo");
    listOfImages.add( javax.imageio.ImageIO.read( blob.getBinaryStream() ) ); 
}
```

[ImageIO JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)